# Adding additional row to personal PowerPoint AddIn

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have created a custom PowerPoint AddIn that consists of a Toolbar with multiple msoControlButtons that execute a macro upon being clicked. As I keep adding more buttons, they are added horizontally (see image). I'd like the buttons to be put on a second row instead e.g. the F button is below the A button.

```
Dim oToolbar As CommandBar
Dim oButton As CommandBarButton
Dim MyToolbar As String

MyToolbar = "Kewl Tools"

On Error Resume Next   
Set oToolbar = CommandBars.Add(Name:=MyToolbar, _
    Position:=msoBarFloating, Temporary:=True)
If Err.Number <> 0 Then  
      Exit Sub
End If

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
Set oButton = oToolbar.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)

With oButton

     .DescriptionText = ""   
     .Caption = "Do Button1 Stuff"    
     .OnAction = "Button1"  
     .Style = msoButtonIcon    
     .FaceId = 52       
End With
```

[Toolbar Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeIHr.png)

Comment: There is a way to do this, somewhat, I'll try to answer below, but I'd mention that since you're doing PowerPoint Add-ins, which come with their own extra level of complexity (e.g., versus Excel) such that you can't debug without hacking your registry, you can't re-save, update or recompile PPAM format, you'll be best-served to use the modern ribbon-based approach. There's a learning curve to it, but you have a lot more freedom over the layout and design than you do using the older methods.

Comment: NB: if you're building this simply as a PPTM file, that caveat regarding extra complexity is not so severe. Debugging is still requiring the registry hack, but you can save/re-compile on demand in PPTM. Just not in PPAM. But a PPTM is not really an add-in, it's just a macro-enabled presentation.

Comment: @DavidZemens That's right - I just use a macro-enabled presentation and write, test, and re-test my macros. Only upon finishing a macro do I save it as a PPAM and add it to my toolbar. What is your method for adding the button to the second row?

Comment: Yeah it's a really painful way to develop PPAM. When I was doing a lot of this a few years ago, I had some helper functions that exported modules (and also re-imported them) so that I could keep the code under a Git repo for versioning/branching, and then I wrote a [python script that would rebuild the PPAM from source](https://github.com/DZemens/Build_Script). Necessity is the mother of invention, I guess :) That script is old, python 2.7 but should still work if you ever need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a long while since I did pure VBA command bars, and this may not be *exactly* what you want, but it's pretty close.

First, create an `msoControlPopup` that will contain your buttons:

```
Dim ButtonGroup as CommandBarPopup
Set ButtonGroup = oToolBar.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlPopup)
ButtonGroup.BeginGroup = True
With ButtonGroup.Controls
    'Button 1:
    Set oButton = .Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
    With oButton
         .DescriptionText = ""   
         .Caption = "Do Button1 Stuff"    
         .OnAction = "Button1"  
         .Style = msoButtonIcon    
         .FaceId = 52       
    End With

    'Button 2:
    Set oButton = .Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
    With oButton
         .DescriptionText = ""   
         .Caption = "This is Button 2!"    
         .OnAction = "Button2"  
         .Style = msoButtonIcon    
         .FaceId = 99       
    End With

    ' repeat adding buttons as needed

End With
```

**Example:**  Each of Data / Sig. Testing / Charts is an `CommandBarPopup` item, and each of those contains a sequence of `CommandBarButtons` implemented in the manner described above. Example illustrates the same approach from Excel, but this should work just the same in PowerPoint.

[image]

Comment: Do you how to add only the Command Bar Pop Up to the Quick Access Toolbar in PowerPoint? Currently when doing so it creates an icon in my QAT which I have to click on and then click on my pop up, thus creating extra work in the process. A workaround would be helpful.

Comment: You've added a custom Toolbar, which contains 1 or more ButtonGroup(s). You add that toolbar to your QAT which gets its own little icon. You have to click on that icon to expose the ButtonGroup(s) or other controls belonging to the Toolbar at the top-most level. Your toolbar is nested: it contains 1 or more ButtonGroup which contain CommandButtons. To access the command buttons you have to access the toolbar, either by the (extra step) icon on QAT, or directly via the Add-Ins Ribbon.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks.